# Sharing an image in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, image, windows-phone-8.1, share

I'd like to share an image in my app. However, the image is not located in a folder but it is "taken dynamically". Basically i have an Image object

```
Image i = new Image() { Source = await CreateBitmapFromElement(stackpanel1) };
```

where CreateBitmapFromElement is defined as follows

```
private async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CreateBitmapFromElement(FrameworkElement uielement)
{
   try
   {
       var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
       await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);
       return renderTargetBitmap;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
   }
   return null;
}
```

The Windows Phone Share Contract allows to share images located in the Picture Library (for example), but what should i use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += OnShareDataRequested;
                base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            }

            protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested -= OnShareDataRequested;
                base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            }

private void OnShareDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs _dataRequestedEventArgs)
        {


            DataRequest request = _dataRequestedEventArgs.Request;
            request.Data.Properties.Title = "KeyTreat Sticker";
            request.Data.Properties.Description = "KeyTreat Sticker: " + StickerName;

            // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
            // we need to get the deferral first.
            DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();

            // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
            try
            {
                request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItemsObject);

                request.Data.Properties.Thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(StorageFileObject);
                request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(StorageFileObject));
            }
            finally
            {
                deferral.Complete();
            }



        }
```